# How can I pass tables to stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data like this, and one procedure is going to populate data in it like this,

```
DECLARE @ClaimChanges TABLE (
    ChangeType                      NVARCHAR(10)
    ,contract_id                    int NOT NULL
    ,dispatch_id                    int NOT NULL
    ,dispatch_claim_id              int NOT NULL
    ,item_no                        VARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,old_units                      VARCHAR(100) NULL
);
```

I would then like to pass that data to a different stored procedure which would be defined like this,

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ct_audit_oncost](
    @table TABLE readonly,
    @OutValue nvarchar(255) = null output
)
as  
-- some stuff
go
```

I gather this is not possible as I am getting an error,

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.
```

Comment: It absolutely is possible. You just can't arbitrarily pass a table though. It needs to be defined as a user defined table type. Then you can pass them via table valued parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table valued parameters are supported since 2008 version.
However, you can't just pass any table you want, first you need to define a user defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyUDT as TABLE
(
ChangeType                      NVARCHAR(10)
,contract_id                    int NOT NULL
,dispatch_id                    int NOT NULL
,dispatch_claim_id              int NOT NULL
,item_no                        VARCHAR(100) NULL
,old_units                      VARCHAR(100) NULL
)
```

Then you can use it in your stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ct_audit_oncost]
(
    @table dbo.MyUDT readonly,
    @OutValue nvarchar(255) = null output
)
as  
    -- some stuff
go
```

Please note you should also use it to declare the table to send to the database:

```
DECLARE @Out nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @ClaimChanges as dbo.MyUdt

INSERT INTO @ClaimChanges (ColumnsList) VALUES (ValuesList)

EXEC ct_audit_oncost @ClaimChanges, @Out output
```

Comment: Yeah that is a good point. But I don't particularly want to define a table type just for this 1 purpose as I will never use it again. I was hoping something dynamic was possible.

Comment: But I could unpivot the data, so I have a more generic structure I can reuse. Thanks, you got me thinking. In any case what I am asking cannot be done directly, so you have answered the question.